# Getting App install parameters?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin

How do I get the parameters set when installing the App to SharePoint 2013?

So, when the user has to give the app permissions (at install) to a certain list, how do I get the chosen list?

Thanks

Picture to clarify: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaXiM.png

Comment: I think you need to extend this question, it is a bit unclear what you are asking :)

Comment: Sorry for that :), what is unclear? I am trying to get the permissions that the app is given at installation.

Comment: Aren't you specifying the permissions in the AppManifest.xml? Sorry, but I fail to find the use of getting these permissions :)

Comment: Yes I am, I specified the permissions for a list. The list is chosen at installation, and I want to know what list was chosen.. Very useful if you want to get the appropriate data from SharePoint.

Comment: Ok, I understand your objective now

Comment: So, any ideas? I'm trying to get the application trust

Comment: Marius has written this: http://nettitude.wordpress.com/2013/01/14/sharepoint-2013-app-permissions-scope/ Seems that you only grant the right to work with lists, so if you require permissions to list you should be granted to all the lists in the scope

Comment: That's the thing, I only want the permission to be set to 1 single list. That's why the option is there. Then afterwards, I want to get the chosen list at runtime. I don't want to give read / write access to the entire site, most users won't easily accept that.